# Need to reverse File but last line has no Carriage Return, so first item of Reversed List has 2 lines in it

Tags: python, file, line, return, reverse

Here is the file

```
303620.43,6187793.62
303663.61,6187757.08
303652.22,6187702.51
303580.10,6187685.43
303551.63,6187737.15
303574.88,6187775.11
303610.94,6187773.69
```

When it is reversed I get

```
303610.94,6187773.69303574.88,6187775.11
303551.63,6187737.15
303580.10,6187685.43
303652.22,6187702.51
303663.61,6187757.08
303620.43,6187793.62
```

How do I  ensure that the Last line when reversed has a `'\n'` ?

Answer (score 5):

Use `rstrip` to remove the newline (and other trailing whitespace) off *all* lines, then rely on `print` to put it back in.

```
a = [ln.rstrip() for ln in open('datafile.txt')]
a.reverse()
for ln in a:
    print(ln)
```

Comment: Or if you're not writing code that prints this to stdout, then you can always just add it back when re-saving the file (ie. your_write_handle.write(a + '\n')

Answer (score 1):

In your code, after you've read a line, check that it ends in `'\n'`. If it doesn't, append a `'\n'` and carry on as you're doing already.

The [`endswith`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method will probably come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for larsmans response.An other solution is to use the splitlines method of string objects:

```
myFile = open(filePath, 'r')
lines = myFile.read().splitlines() #by default splitlines removes trailing '\n'
myFile.close()
lines.reverse()
for line in lines:
    print line
```

Comment: Thank you all... slowly getting a handle on Python